# Stylus mixin to alternate rules in nested classes of the same name?

Tags: stylus

What would be a smooth stylus (or sass) mixin to alternate rules in nested classes of the same name?

```
.ember-view
  border: 1px solid red
  .ember-view
    border: 1px solid white
    .ember-view
      border: 1px solid blue
      .ember-view
        // repeat? options etc.
```

I've tried a few things to no avail and just went back to nesting 10 deep to avoid wasting time... however - I believe that someone out there has the answer.

```
alterate-border-color(a, b, c, ...)
  // logic
  // border-color: 1px solid n

.ember-view
  alternate-border-color('red', 'white', 'blue')
```

Answered! by @blonfu: here is [a CodePen](https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/eEKMvg/) with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I archieve a solution. The problem was prevent repeat the entire selector in each iteration of the loop, I just needed to repeat `.ember-view` selector and I use a little weird code to get that. I hope it is useful for you:

**Stylus**

```
alterate-border-color(colors...)
  $selector =  selector()
  for color in colors
    /{$selector}
      border-color: 1px solid color
    $selector = $selector + " " + selector()

.ember-view
  alterate-border-color(red , blue, yellow, green)
```

**CSS output**

```
.ember-view {
  border-color: 1px solid #f00;
}
.ember-view .ember-view {
  border-color: 1px solid #00f;
}
.ember-view .ember-view .ember-view {
  border-color: 1px solid #ff0;
}
.ember-view .ember-view .ember-view .ember-view {
  border-color: 1px solid #008000;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @blonfu

Comment: I'll have to look up that `/{...` syntax

Comment: the `/` takes the selector to the root, like @at-root in SASS: http://stylus-lang.com/docs/selectors.html#root-reference